# Why does my VS 2015 still use the C++98 compiler version?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I tought my VS 2015 use the new C++11 compiler version.
Does I have missed somewhat?
I tried different Platform Toolset: v90 ..v140. None helps.

Used code to check the C++ compiler version: [How to get the C++ version](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/90675/)

```
#include <iostream>

//  Print the current used C++ version
int main()
{
  int version = __cplusplus;
  if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::wcout << "C++11\n";
  else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::wcout << "C++98\n";
  else std::wcout << "pre-standard C++\n";
}
```

The console output is: C++98   for all Plattform Toolset

Comment: That's because `__cplusplus` is probably `201402`.

Comment: Test standard versions with `>=`, always. Otherwise your code stops "guessing" correctly when the *next* standard comes out.

Comment: Even Visual Studio 2017, when set to `ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest)` reports 199711.

Comment: Microsoft does what Microsoft wants. vOv

Comment: Then how do I know if a C++11 feature is there? Do I have to use _MSC_VER instead?  (Ex: _MSC_VER == 1900 for VS2015)