# Why is the Visual Studio Community 2017 C++ standard C++98?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, standards

Yesterday I upgraded to the latest VS Community 2017 (the previous one was installed last year) and wanted to check the C++ standard. So I run the following code that checks it, and as it turns out, I have C++98:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << __cplusplus << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Which outputs

> 199711

Why don't I have the latest C++ standard?

[image: screenshot of the code, output and vs version]

Comment: Try changing the related project properties.

Comment: You should build with `/std:c++17` and `/permissive-` for example.

Comment: Don't trust `__cplusplus`. VS2017 supports C++17 just fine - you just need to pass the correct commandline option(s) to enable it.

Comment: [For Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117953/why-does-my-vs-2015-still-use-the-c98-compiler-version?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The value of `__cplusplus` is temporarily intentionally non-conformant by default for current versions of Visual Studio in order to avoid breaking existing code. It does not mean your compiler does not support any C++11 (or newer) features.

Quoting from [MSVC now correctly reports __cplusplus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/):

> ### /Zc:__cplusplus
>
> You need to compile with the `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch to see the updated value of the `__cplusplus` macro. We tried updating the macro by default and discovered that a lot of code doesn’t compile correctly when we change the value of `__cplusplus`. We’ll continue to require use of the `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch for all minor versions of MSVC in the 19.xx family.

Comment: success! I followed the instructions on setting /Zc:__cplusplus to enabled and I see I have c++14 (201402).
This is the guide for doing this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2017

Comment: If the actual standard the compiler is enforcing is the focus of concern, rather than the value of that macro, you can right click on your Project in the Solution Explorer. and Select `Properties`. Then expand the `C/C++` menu on the left, and choose the `Language` submenu. There you can choose `++14`,`++17`, or `++latest`.

Comment: Even with C++ set to a particular C++ standard, one's compiler may not support every feature for that standard.  Here's a [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) program that can help discern if one's compiler supports the desired core or library feature, which `__cplusplus` may be misleading if used as a check.